# Passing value selected cell to another ViewController

Tags: arrays, swift2

I have two ViewControllers. For the first ViewController, it displays my Array data on the table. I want to get the indexPath of the selected cell, and pass this data to another ViewController.

In my First ViewController

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {
var nameList = [NameManager]()

    @IBOutlet weak var NameTable: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NameTable.dataSource = self
        GetData()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func GetData(){
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/bPfifKWNaq?indent=2")!)
        request.HTTPMethod = "GET"

        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in

            if let error = error {
                print(error)
            }
            if let data = data{
                do{
                    let resultJSON = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions())
                    let resultArray = resultJSON as? NSArray
                    for jsonObjectString in resultArray!{
                        let code = jsonObjectString["code"] as! String
                        let name = jsonObjectString["name"] as! String
                        let description = jsonObjectString["description"] as! String
                        self.nameList.append(NameManager(code: code, name: name, description: description))
                    }
                    self.nameList.count
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                        self.NameTable.reloadData()
                    })
                }catch _{
                    print("Received not-well-formatted JSON")
                }

            }
            if let response = response {
                let httpResponse = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse
                print("response code = \(httpResponse.statusCode)")
            }

        })
        task.resume()

    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
        let count = nameList.count
        return count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
        let myCell = NameTable.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

        myCell.textLabel?.text = nameList[indexPath.row].name
        myCell.detailTextLabel?.text = nameList[indexPath.row].description

        return myCell
    }
```

In my Second ViewController, which is also another class, I want to capture the indexPath of what was selected. Using the index value, I search my Array and pass that particular object to the next class. I don't have codes for this as I don't know how it works.

Comment: How do you display both controllers? Do you display second after cell selection in the first one?

Comment: Using navigation controller, on click of the cell, it will bring me to the next controller. Both uses different class.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a property outside the scope of your class and then set that within the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`  method. That property could be accessed in your second view controller. You’ll want to look at the tableview method `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` as that will be where you set your property to the cell that’s been selected.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
appDelegate().index = indexPath.row
}
```

I’ve made a super simple [project on github](https://github.com/montalban/test) showing two ways of creating a property outside the scope of your view controller. One way is creating a variable within `AppDelegate` to be accessed via a singleton, the other is a Globals.swift file.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry I'm new to swift programming. So by creating a property and setting the value at `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, at my other class, I have to also instantiate a new object of my previous class, which when extracting, it will return me as null?

Comment: I updated that project on github (see link above) to be a simple demo of passing value from one view controller to another. HTH

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass values to the controller which pops after tapping on the cell, using a singleton wouldn't be an elegant way. If you are using storyboards, then you have to use 'prepare for segue'. You implement the method in the class that handles the transfer and set all the properties in another view controller.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "SecondVC") {
        // set properties
    }
}
```